# How do I get a localized string from a Form resouce resx file in code?

Tags: forms, winforms, localization, globalization

[image]

I tried to call it as below but I couldn't. That's why the code is incomplete

```cs
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (ResXResourceSet resxSet = new ResXResourceSet(resxFile))
    {
        this.Text = resxSet.GetString("buttonError");
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming the path is correct, you probably wanted to get `resxSet.GetString("buttonError.Text")` -- Are you sure you want to access UI culture related values like this?